# Can the empty set be a component interval?

Tags: real-analysis

In the textbook I’m working with there is a problem that specifies that for any $I_k$ which is a component interval of $\sigma$, the supremum on the interval, minus the infimum on that interval, $I_k$, is less than some $\epsilon > 0$.

The question is for proving this by case, should I consider the empty set?

Comment: That depends on the definition of "component interval of  $\sigma$".